# How to reference a cell based on a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to reference a cell based on a specific formula in Google Sheets.

For example, if I want to reference cell `A10`, I can't write down cell `A(11-1)` or else I get an error.

In my case, I have a number in cell `C2` that changes based on other values in the spreadsheet. From here, I want to get the information from the cell with row `C2` and column `A` and print that out in cell `D3`.

I've tried putting in the following formula in cell `D3`: `=A(C2)`. But this didn't work.

How can I change the following formula in order to get my result?

Thanks, and sorry if this question is basic and simple, I'm really new to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly need [indirect()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) :

`D3:`  `=INDIRECT("A" & C2)`

Answer (score 1):

or try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, C2))
```

where `1` represents 1st column eg. A column

...but you still need to indirect it